# Average of the first items of tuples in a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, average

I have a dictionary in the form:

```
{"a": (1, 0.1), "b": (2, 0.2), ...}
```

Each tuple corresponds to (score, standard deviation).
How can I take the average of just the first integer in each tuple?
I've tried this:

```
for word in d:
    (score, std) = d[word]
    d[word]=float(score),float(std)
    if word in string:
        number = len(string)
        v = sum(score)
        return (v) / number
```

Get this error:

```
    v = sum(score)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's easy to do using [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  First, you can get all the dictionary values from `d.values()`.  To make a list of just the first item in each value you make a list like `[v[0] for v in d.values()]`.  Then, just take the sum of those elements, and divide by the number of items in the dictionary:

```
sum([v[0] for v in d.values()]) / float(len(d))
```

As Pedro rightly points out, this actually creates the list, and then does the sum.  If you have a huge dictionary, this might take up a bunch of memory and be inefficient, so you would want a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) instead of a list comprehension.  In this case, that just means getting rid of one pair of brackets:

```
sum(v[0] for v in d.values()) / float(len(d))
```

The two methods are compared [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension).

Comment: You don't actually need the list comprehension, `sum` will take any iterable, so the generator expression in `sum(v[0] for v in d.values())` will work without creating the intermediate list.

Comment: Excellent point.  I just think building up the expression like this is a bit clearer.